# How to set plain sheet title in phpexcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to print excel sheet with multiple sheets inside. Everything is working fine except the sheet title. I have set the sheet title and it is coming accordingly. However, with the given sheet title the extra number is also coming which creates confusion. I believe, this is the sheet index number or something but unable to remove it. Here is my code :

```
$y=0;
for ($w=1; $w<3; $w++) :
            $sheetId =$y;
            $objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, $sheetId);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetId);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Week ".$w);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(12);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(14);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(16);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(12);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(10);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(15);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(10);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(17.5);

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetId)->mergeCells('A1:J6');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:J5')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:E')->applyFromArray($centreAlign);
endfor;
```

**Output:**

[image]

The first week 1 and week 2 is correct but in others extra number is coming which is undesirable.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you are executing your posted code twice. This creates two sets of identically-named worksheets (Week 1, Week 2, Week 1, Week 2) which Excel does not like. It automatically adds "1" to repeating titles.

It's not your code that adds 1, it's Excel.

So you need to either maintain global week iterator, so it becomes Week 1, Week 2, Week 3, Week 4:

```
// you may need to do global $week if this code runs in a function
if ( ! isset( $week ) )
  $week = 0;
for ($w=1; $w<3; $w++) :
  // ...
  $week += $w;
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Week ".$week);
  // ...
endfor;
```

Or you need to implement some other sheet naming scheme for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Set sheet name using for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { //two sheet create excel workbook

      $newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();//sheet create 

      $newsheet->setTitle("week". $i); //sheet  name use looping

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have reformat you code and that is perfectly working for me. Please try it

```
 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    define('EOL', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '
');
```

`require_once dirname('your file') . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
        ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
        ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
        ->setCategory("Test result file");
$y = 0;
for ($w = 1; $w < 10; $w++) {
    $sheetId = $y;
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, $sheetId);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetId);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Week " . $w);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(14);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(16);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(15);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(10);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(17.5);

    $styleArray = array(
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true
        )
    );
    $centreAlign = array(
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true
        )
    );

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetId)->mergeCells('A1:J6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:J5')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:E')->applyFromArray($centreAlign);
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$objWriter->save('php://output');
</pre>`

Check below link for my output:
https://www.screencast.com/t/PnQsQZ8JC6dt

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17781111)

Comment: @ ADreNaLiNe-DJ ,I have properly check question and that was exactly work for me then i give ans here. Stack-overflow is not asking us to give only perfect answers to any of question. 

Here all can give their working review. That is exact meaning if stack overflow. If you have that much reputation it doesn't mean any other who has no reputation can't give any answers. Just because of you people our reputation which we get previously will be down. Please don't do that you can help other rather than give them minus points.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is a site for asknig questions abot problems or errors and to find solutions for this. For code reviewing, it's another site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ A reformat is not an answer, it's an advice that you can provide via comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
And I have not reformat any of code, I have write my own code and which i have been used in my project. If i have to reformat the code then i can directly edit code which will provide functionality of stackoverflow. Here i have used my own code.